# Error using native code

Tags: java, eclipse, native, native-code, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have two projects in eclipse. Project1 and Project2. Project1 uses native code which is included with:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("thelibraryname");
}
```

I added Project1 to the build-path of project 2. Project2 calls methods from a class in Project1, which uses the native methods. However, I am getting an error when running Project2:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no
>   thelibraryname in java.library.path

The directory struture of my eclipse project looks like this:

```
Project1
    Android 1.6
    Android Dependancies
    src/
    bin/
    libs/
        armeabi/
            libthelibraryname.so
        armeabi-v7a/
            libthelibraryname.so
        x86/
            libthelibraryname.so
    <some-other-dirs-and-files>
Project2
    src/
        Testing.java
    Junit
    JRE System Library
```

I found that the error has something to do with the native code. Probably I need to provide a reference to the native code somewhere but I could not find how. Note that eclipse does not indicate any errors at compile time, only at runtime.

Any ideas what I can do to fix this? :)

Edit:

- I am running on a 64 bit platform with a 32 bit JRE.
- i tried: -Djava.library.path=/path/to/lib/x86 (and witharmeabi-v7a and armeabi). But it didn't change anything.

Comment: Are you running this on a 64-bit platform? Are you using the 32-bit JRE?

Comment: Have you tried running with `-Djava.library.path=/path/to/lib/folder`?

Comment: For starters, try printing the value of java.library.path property. If your library's location is not on it, you'll need to make sure that it is.

Comment: I edited my answer to answer the comments above.

Comment: If the JRE is 32-bit, then the library you are trying to load needs to also be 32-bit.  Is it?

Answer (score 1):

here is an instruction
use UTF-8 encoding and it will work
http://stijndewitt.wordpress.com/2010/05/05/unicode-utf-8-in-eclipse-java/

Comment: Your link is not right. But I suppose its: http://stijndewitt.wordpress.com/2010/05/05/unicode-utf-8-in-eclipse-java/

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it would help?